# Python equivalent of php pack

Tags: php, python, binary, hex

I have this statement below in php to convert `hex` string to `binary`.

```
$m=pack("H*" , "A88BE9L98990........");
```

I need to do the same in another `python` program ?

Any Ideas ?

Cheers,

Comment: What's the `L` doing there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `binascii` module has `binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)`, which does what you want.

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify("A88BE9L98990")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
# Not sure why there's an L in there... take it out...
>>> binascii.unhexlify("A88BE9989900")
'\xa8\x8b\xe9\x98\x99\x00'
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Original string was too large to post. So i just typed in random.

Answer (score 0):

[python2php](http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.pack/) web site can help you - it suggest using `struct.pack`

Comment: struct.pack does most of what PHP's pack does, but it doesn't handle the hex conversion.