# PHP to python pack('H')

Tags: php, python, hex, pack, nibble

I'm translating an authentication library, written in PHP to Python.  It's all legacy code, the original devs long gone.  They used PHP's 'pack' command to transform a string into hex using the 'H' flag.  PHP's [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) describes this as 'Hex string, high nibble first'.  I read another question ([Python equivalent of php pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892734/python-equivalent-of-php-pack)) which suggested using binascii.unhexlify(), but this complains whenever I pass in a non-hex character.

So my question is what does the PHP pack function do with non-hex characters?  Does it throw them away, or is there an extra step that performs a translation. Is there a better method in Python than binascii.unhexlify?

So pack'ing 'H*'

```
php -r 'print pack("H*", md5("Dummy String"));'
```

Returns

```
??????=?PW??
```

In python:

```
secret = binascii.unhexlify( "Dummy String" )
TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

Thanks for the help.

[EDIT]

So DJV was fundamentally right.  I needed to convert the value into md5 first, however that's where it's interesting.  In python the md5 library returns binary data via the 'digest' method.

In my case I could skip all the binascii calls and just use

```
md5.md5('Dummy String').digest()
```

Which is the same in PHP as:

pack("H*", md5("Dummy String"));

Fun stuff. Good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need it the other way around. `"Dummy String"` is not a valid number in `hex`. You can `hexlify` it:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify('Dummy String')
'44756d6d7920537472696e67'
```

but not `unhexlify` it. `unhexlify` takes a string in `hex` and turns it into it's ASCII representation:

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify('44756d6d7920537472696e67')
'Dummy String'
```

What you need is to `md5` the string (`"Dummy String"` in our case) and `unhexlify` it's hash:

```
import binascii
import hashlib

the_hash = hashlib.md5('Dummy String').hexdigest()
print the_hash
the_unhex = binascii.unhexlify(the_hash)
print the_unhex
```

Which yields the hash, and the unhexlified hash:

```
ec041da9f891c09b3d1617ba5057b3f5
ЛLЬ-ю?=¦PWЁУ
```

**Note:** although the output doesn't look exactly like yours - "??????=?PW??", the "PW" and "=" in both, makes me pretty certain it's correct.

More on [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) and [binascii](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I think you're on the right track there.  I'll update this question once I get the final answer I'm looking for.