# Does python has similar function as pack() in php?

Tags: php, python, pack

In php, `pack("V", $id);` It can change the "id" into binary with the 32 bits , unsigned, little endian format. How can we do the same this using python?

Another thing, I try the following code:

```
my_input = 10
binary_string = pack("<I", my_input)
print my_input
```

The output is :

```
▯▯▯
```

what is wrong with my code or my pycharm ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python equivalent of php pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892734/python-equivalent-of-php-pack)

Comment: Are you sure that was the output of *that precise program*? The output should have been `10`. Please don't retype or summarize your code, please copy-paste a short, complete program, including any import statements. See [mcve] for helpful information.

Comment: Let me introduce you to your new best friend: http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.pack/

Answer (score 1):

To create a 32-bit unsigned little endian memory region in Python, use `struct.pack` just as you have:

```
binary_string = pack("<I", my_input)
```

You can then store those bytes in a file like so:

```
with open("my_input.bin", "wb") as f:
    f.write(binary_string)
```